# UITableView: rendered cells count

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've designed UITableView which displays custom cells of big height (height almost equals to screen's one). Now I got the following behavior: next row begins rendering only when tableview stops scrolling (I can see it as cellForRowAtIndexPath calls exactly at that moment). It causes blank screen for a moment which is quite annoying.
TableCell initialization takes nothing (~0.0000002s) so it can not be an issue. Now the question: is there a way to force UITableView render a number of invisible cells? Saying, 5 more.

Comment: Are you using re-usable cells ?

Comment: sorry forgot to mention. yes, reusable

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. Can you share some code?

Comment: Have you considered using scroll view instead of table where you can preload next view before hand, something like preload the prev and next views of the currently displayed view...just a thought.

Comment: yeah, I've considered... but don't you think it's not quite trivial and actually UITableView implements exactly what you describe

Comment: UITableView extends ScrollView, so it does similar thing, but you'll have more control of what and when to load the next view using ScrollView. In TableView approach, it calls the datasource to get the new row/cell but you don't have much control on when it calls, and how can you tell it to pre-populate the next row too. It may not be as hard as you think. Here's the sample provided by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007795-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: Actually, you can tell the data-source method to populate cells before they appear, by explicitly calling the methods. This is the reason why i asked if the cells were reusable. It wouldn't work on non-reusable cells, as they would redraw all cells, instead of reusing them.
Once the cells have been plotted by explicit call, they will just be reused.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, try to think of some logic to calculate when the next cell is about to be plotted. Then explicitly call `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, that way, the cell's `drawRect` will be called before it appears.

One option would be to call `[yourTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:indexPath.section]` inside your `scrollViewDidScroll` for tableView. Using `visibleCells` would be a good option. here the indexPath.row and indexPath.section can be from your NSIndexPath object that you declare, and set in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

But i'll tell you beforehand, this is just a hack, cannot say it's good practice.

EDIT: You can set a `CGFloat` as current table offset everytime you call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` explicitly, and compare this value with current offset, as the table scrolls. If your current offset is about to reach this value + cellHeight (get cell height explicitly with `heightForRowAtIndexPath` if not stored), then call your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: thanks for suggestion but is seems wrong. I tried to reproduce and no success: explicit call of cellForRowAtIndexPath doesn't force UITableView to push new cells.

Comment: In that case, i'm unsure if your cells are reusable.
Try placing an `NSLog` in the `drawRect` and see if cells already rendered are re-drawn (on scrolling upwards). If they produce logs again, means they are not being reused.
If they, in fact, are being reused, I'm sorry i'm out of ideas.